# Hacking attempt. Can you please interpret these codes?

Tags: security

Can you please interpret these codes? 200 means it is successful.

```
125.118.0.239 - - [28/Oct/2015:12:12:29 +0000] "\x81!\x01\x03\x03\x01\b" 200 113972 "-" "-"
125.119.13.51 - - [28/Oct/2015:12:12:31 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 200 113972 "-" "-"
```

I am using Apache 2.2.31-1.el6 on CentOS.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

\x**XX** is an escaped hex byte. This is likely an attempt at a buffer overflow attack of some kind.

I'd caution you against thinking that an HTTP 200 response means they're succeeding though, that just means your server was able to respond to their query.